# How would you call such mental attachments related to food and cuisine?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice, food

How are the.following two cases called?

- Some people are very stuck to gourmet or tasty food, rather than plain food, and hooked to exquisite or sophisticated preparation or cooking styles，rather than simple preparation and cooking.
- Some people are very stuck to food and cuisine that they grew up with or are used to. That doesn't change even after they migrate to a place with different food or cuisine.

How would you call such mental or psychological dependences or attachments? Would it be called "a complex of ... (gastronomy)"?

Comment: What's wrong with 'gourmet' for the first type? (PS 'stuck to' is an odd way of putting it.)

Comment: @KateBunting - I sometimes visit restaurants in the Flunch chain when I am in France. _Ou les gourmands rencontrent le gourmets_.

Comment: "Stuck to" and "hooked to" are distinctly odd, I doubt if a native speaker would use them. "Attached to" would be more natural.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you could say *has a taste for*, meaning a preference for a certain type of food without the connotation that the person is actively avoiding other types. *A refined palate* would imply that the person appreciates fine foods.  *Epicurean* also works and has a neutral/positive connotation, though not every listener may understand the meaning.

There's also *foodie* which is someone who seeks out new or unique foods. In some contexts it also implies that the person is a food snob and scorns simple or fast food and the people who eat it. This is a connotation I reject. I think of a foodie as someone who, when visiting a new country, will try the local cuisine instead of going to McDonald's.

In the second case, there's not a single specific word that comes to mind, though I do know many people who fit that description. Depending on how much negative connotation you want to attach to it, you could say "not adventurous" (fairly neutral), "a steak-and-potatoes type of person" (if they eat that kind of food), "boring" (negative), etc.

Comment: thanks. The first is more of simple versus fancy cooking, gourmet tasted food vs plain food. Would complex of ... be suitable for describing the two mentalities in my post?

Comment: No, "complex of..." would indicate a clinically unhealthy level of attachment.

Comment: I am interested in expressions of positive, neutral, or negative connotation, though I am holding a slightly negative attitude towards both